# how to check if an integer variable take an integer value in c#

Tags: c#

how to check if a function argument is of type integer in c# i.e if I have a variable for example, I need a method to check that the value is an integer value.  the method return true  if it is an integer and if the value is equal to a double value then method returns false.

Comment: Use case? If you're really talking about dealing with user inputs, for example, you're likely getting them as strings and can use int.TryParse. Otherwise, you'll need to be a bit more descriptive.

Comment: `I have an integer variable for example x I need a method to check that the value of x is an integer` No comment

Comment: @I4V: "No comment" is a comment.

Comment: An integer variable can only take integer values. That's why it's called an integer.

Comment: You want to return false if the integer contains a double? Really?

Comment: for example the I declare a variable and the value of it will be from the user I want to make a method to check if the user enter the value and the value isn't integer the method display error message ,I explain my problem with an example but I don't need the method for this reason I need the method for anything else

Comment: Integer variable always has integer in it.

Comment: Guys, give the OP a break. Obviously not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you are looking for:

```
public static bool TryParse(
    string s,
    out int result
)
```

Here is an example of the implementation:

```
string userInput = "4";
int convertedInput;
if(Int32.TryParse(userInput, out convertedInput) {
   //the userInput was a valid integer. convertedInput is now set to the integer equivalent of "4"
}
else {
   //the userInput was ***not*** a valid integer. 
}
```

Here is the MSDN documentation:

[Int32.TryParse Method (String, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Check these methods out, it might suit your needs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx

Comment: thanks ,but I don't want to check the conversion from on data type to another,All I need for example the I declare a variable and the value of it will be from the user I want to make a method to check if the user enter the value and the value isn't integer the method display error message ,I explain my problem with an example but I don't need the method for this reason I need the method for anything else –

Comment: let me try to rephrase it to understand you. You want to make a function that takes an argument from the user, and you want that function to see if that argument is an integer or not?

Comment: if that's the case then these functions will do it for you. Use the int32.tryparse in your function to check if the input is an integer or not.